# Angular 2 & Firebase: Async Pipe vs. Subscribe

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it better to subscribe the data I get from a database or use the async pipe?

I can't reload the page if I use the subscribe method. With async pipes this isn't a problem. But I think it's a little bit slower another disadvantage is that I have multiple async-pipe-operations.

I'm using the async pipe within the ngFor-loop if I need multiple datas from one list. If I only use single datas there is of coure no loop.
But is there also a solution like if I had less objects inside a list that I have to use the async pipe and if there are very much objects inside a list I should use the subscribe.

What's your opinion? Which one is better? Whiche one is faster? Or doesn't it matter?

By the way: is there a possibility to reload the page and use subscribe?